# Rails not catching exception in rescue block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

`User` model has defined indexes to be searched using `ThinkingSphinx`. However when I stop my `searchd` deamon, I would like my method to fail gracefully and not throw an error. Normally I do this by using a rescue block for catching exceptions. But in this case, it still throws the error and the `puts` statement is never executed.

```
def search_users(key)
  begin
    search_results =  User.search(key,options)
  rescue Exception
    puts "Hello World!!!"
    search_results = []
  end
  return search_results
end
```

Following is the error i get:

`Riddle::ConnectionError (Connection to 127.0.0.1 on 3201 failed. Connection refused - connect(2)):`

Is there any way out?

Comment: Tried this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/thinking-sphinx/PGT22AqAvZo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

> Add the :populate => true option to your search calls.
>
> Normally, Thinking Sphinx lazily loads search results (allowing for
>   sphinx scopes and such) - but if you want the rescue to take effect,
>   then you'll need to force the results to load immediately - hence the
>   :populate option.

Refer the link posted above for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

Given ruby return semantics, you can compress your code:

```
def search_users(key)
  begin
    User.search(key,options)
  rescue
    puts "Hello World!!!"
    []
  end
end
```

It is evil to rescue `Exception`. Just use `rescue`, which rescues `StandardError`, which captures most of the stuff you want it to. Otherwise you also capture `SyntaxError`, `LoadError`, `SystemExit` and other stuff you don't intend. In this case, `rescue Riddle::ConnectionError` is appropriate, but not necessary.